# How to get column value from sample data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do following process:

1. Get sample random row form data frame.

   df = df.sample()
2. Then I want to get value from column 'amount' I do following, but it is not working.

   amount = df['auth_amount'].iloc[0]

Anyone knows how do do it. My code works only for first row.

Comment: `df.loc[df.sample().index,'auth amount']`

Comment: if you dont want the index value as well, you can add `.to_numpy()[0]` to the end